# Is it acceptable to capitalize class names and attributes when referencing my programming code in a message?

Tags: capitalization

In programming we often create reusable data structures that contain attributes to store information.  For example, if writing a piece of software that has to do with cars we may have a `Car` class that has various attributes like `color`, `make`, `year`, etc.  If I am writing about my software is it acceptable to capitalize these class and attribute names?

e.g.

`Should the Color attribute in the Car class contain pink?`

`What does Make mean?`

Comment: In the light of your comment below "I am writing to the people contracting us that have no programming experience.", surely you should be **avoiding** the use of programming terminology and should be asking questions / writing documentation in English. You're the one they have paid to translate between English & programming languages. But if you **really, really must** use programming terms, then define/explain them at the beginning so that they understand what these strange-looking camelCase words mean. This is a common-sense question, not an English language question!

Comment: @TrevorD Well, I am not really using programming terms.  I am using class and attribute names that refer to actual items in their business system.  For example, `I added filing date to the deed record`.  For some reason I was feeling the urge to write `I added Filing Date to the Deed record` because `filingDate` and `Deed` are an attribute and class in my code.  The message would be short so I don't think I would want to add a header section with definitions as suggested by some below.

Answer (score 3):

Not if the language is case sensitive. You would want to write them in the same way as they were written in your program. For example, if taking about the `int` type in C, you would want to write `int` even if it's at the start of a sentence.

(Originally posted as a comment.)

Comment: Say I had an `int yearModel`.  Do you think I should use `yearModel` when writing about the program?  It seems kind of messy to do that, and the person I am writing to may have no idea that attribute names are often [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: Yes, you should. Write them in monospace to distinguish them from the main text, if you want. I would say it's terrible practice to use a different name for attributes in your documentation. (Different capitalization would essentially make it a different name.) Unless you wanted to pleonastically refer to your Color attribute as "the attribute representing color", you should use the same capitalization.

Comment: You are absolutely right about documentation.  Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I am writing to the people contracting us that have no programming experience.

Comment: In that case I don't see how `yearModel` would make any sense to them even if written differently. You might want to define `yearModel` as "Blah blah blah" at the start or something, and refer to it as `yearModel` throughout the text.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you should choose a different font for the program identifiers.  For example:

1. If your normal text is in a nice serif font, then put your code identifiers in an ugly sans instead.
2. If your normal text is already is an ugly sans, then put your code identifiers in a `mono` instead.

Comment: Monospace is best.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius For code excerpts where vertical alignment is paramount, certainly. But when you are simply quoting an identifier, I find that a sans contrasts well enough with a serif, and doesn't screw with your justification at all so badly as mono does.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was just expressing my love of monospace. =)

Comment: @Kaiser: Don't you mean your love of `monospace`?

Comment: `:o I guess I do.`

Answer (score 2):

When writing documentation for programmers, it's best to use exactly the names that are in the software to minimize confusion.  You can insert extra words to respect capitalization rules.  To avoid starting a sentence with the lowercase variable name `size`, for instance: "Variable `size` is always less than `length`."

When writing for a technical audience that probably isn't going to work directly with the program code, use names that maximize readability and follow programming language conventions.  It is common for conference papers to use cleaned-up and abbreviated names (of functions, data types, and so forth), as it's generally understood that they're smoothing over messy and boring details to focus on the important parts of the software.